# Check if Local Notifications allowed

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications

I'm repeating a Local Notification at the same time every day.

Right now everything is working fine, **except when Notifications are toggled OFF, then back ON, there is a build up of notifications from the days it was OFF.**

Is there a best way to check if toggled OFF then back ON, and clear all old notifications?

Thanks!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
    UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];

    // before we create any new ones, cancel all existing notifications
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *comp = [cal components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    comp.hour = 19; // 19 = 7PM
    comp.minute = 45; // 7:45 PM
    comp.second = 01; // 7:45:01 PM

    localNotification.fireDate = [cal dateFromComponents:comp];
    localNotification.alertBody = @"Local Notification in iOS8";
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitDay;

    // this will schedule the notification to fire at the fire date
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
    // this will fire the notification right away, it will still also fire at the date we set
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before presenting the notification check if the users settings allow it:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
    UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];

    // before we create any new ones, cancel all existing notifications
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    if ([[[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings] types] != UIUserNotificationTypeNone) {

        UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

        NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
        NSDateComponents *comp = [cal components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
        comp.hour = 19; // 19 = 7PM
        comp.minute = 45; // 7:45 PM
        comp.second = 01; // 7:45:01 PM

        localNotification.fireDate = [cal dateFromComponents:comp];
        localNotification.alertBody = @"Local Notification in iOS8";
        localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitDay;

        // this will schedule the notification to fire at the fire date
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
        // this will fire the notification right away, it will still also fire at the date we set
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Just put that line of code before `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];` and it does the trick?  Just checking to make sure I'm not missing anything.

Comment: This checks to make sure notifications are allowed before you bother to create and schedule one.

Comment: Oh awesome!  I'm getting an error saying `no visible @interface for uiusernotificationsettings declares the selector maypresentusernotificationoftype`, any ideas?

Comment: Weird I guess that method is actually private but Apple accidentally included it in their documentation. I updated the code with an alternative way to do this.

Comment: That is weird.  Thanks I'll try this out!

Answer (score -2):

On toggle on event, try following -

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```